# How can I define a refinement type that return this.type in a Scala 3 Macro?

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros, scala-3

I have been trying to figure out how to create the following refinement within a Scala 3 Macro:

```
{
  def foo: this.type
}
```

Note: I know that self reference in refinement is deprecated but there are quite a few cyclic reference bugs that I am working around.

I can get as far as:

```
Refinement(TypeRepr.of[Object], "foo", ???)
```

But how do I get a `TypeRepr` for `this.type`?

I can't use `This(symbol)` because there is no symbol for the refinement type here.

I tried a `RecursiveType` like:

```
RecursiveType { parentExp =>
  val resultType = This(parentExp.typeSymbol).tpe
  Refinement(TypeRepr.of[Object], "foo", resultType)
}
```

But this blows up with a `ClassCastException` because `parentExp.typeSymbol` is not a class symbol.

Do I have to create a `newClassSymbol` and `TypeDef` and then refer to that symbol for `This` and elsewhere in my macro rather than inline as a `TypeRepr`?

Oh I should mention that I am not using quotes here because for my real use case, the members are not known ahead of time and as far as I know you cannot splice definitions.